# How to prevent gunicorn access log from getting on to the console and reload properly?

Tags: pyramid, gunicorn, paster

I have a pyramid application and I wanted to serve it using gunicorn instead of the default waitress. But the biggest problem I have is that there is not enough documentation on the subject anywhere.

Here is what I would like on my dev machine

1. Use `pserve` to serve the app on my machine because it comes with code reload on change in code
2. Configure ini files to have 8 threads of gunicorn because we have the same thing on server

I have the config like this now:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn#main
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 6543
proc_name = mvc_gunicorn
pidfile = mvc_gunicorn.pid
errorlog = mvc_error.log
accesslog = mvc_access.log
workers = 8
```

It works great except

1. But the annoying access log gets to the console. How can I avoid that?
2. The code reload does not work because threads do not die immediately. I have to start it manually myself. Can reload on pserve me made to wait a bit or can the threads in gunicorn die fast?

On a related note is there a place where I can find all the params that can be used in INI file to configure gunicorn?